# RecyclerView - Implement B&W items images according to flag

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I try to create a `RecyclerView` that shows images. I want to implement a feature that if some variable status is "CLOSE" then make the image item B&W, else leave it RGB as it is.

I have an Object named `Player`. `Player` contains: `int id`, `int imgAdrs`, `String status`.

I pass to `RecyclerView` an array of all players image addresses `allPlayers`, and an array of all players status `mStatus`.

Since I am trying to avoid to have 2 pictures for each item (one RGB and the second BW) - I tried applying the BW filter on the `ImageView` items during the ViewHolder constructor initialization.

But the `status` variable is not passed to the `ViewHolder` (the `status` is `null`), and visible only to the `RecyclerViewAdapter`.

Could someone help me figure this out?

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Integer> allPlayers = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mStatus = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Integer> mImages, ArrayList<String> mStatus) {
        this.allPlayers = mImages;
        this.mStatus = mStatus;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lay_players_item_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {   
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(allPlayers.get(position))
                .into(holder.image);

        holder.status = mStatus.get(position);
        holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "(:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { //How many items are in the list
        return allPlayers.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            ImageView image;
        RelativeLayout parentLayout;
        String status;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);

            if (status.equals("CLOSE")) {
                ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
                matrix.setSaturation(0);

                ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
                image.setColorFilter(filter);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in onBindViewHolder

```
        if (mStatus.get(position).equals("CLOSE")) {
            ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
            matrix.setSaturation(0);

            ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
            holder.image.setColorFilter(filter);

        }
```

You can only edit any view inside onBindViewHolder method. Viewholder is like a holder which only holds your view.

Let me know if this solves your problem ?

Comment: Thanks! You're the best:)